# How to query mongoengine by using contains in list?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

If I have a collection with a list field similar to the below.

```
class Post(Document):
   tags = ListField(StringField())
```

Let's say I have a post with the tags: interesting, funny.

And if I want to search for posts with tags fulfill any of the search terms, how should I do?

Say if I put in the search terms "interesting" and "fantastic", the above post should be there in the result set.

I tried to read through [documentation](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#query-operators) but seems like there is no such operator.  "all" and "in" are similar but can't perform what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually just a simple query eg:

```
class Post(Document):
    tags = ListField(StringField())

>>> Post.drop_collection()
>>> Post(tags=["hello", "world"]).save()
>>> Post(tags=["cat", "dog"]).save()

>>> Post.objects(tags__in=['hello', 'cat']).count()
... 2
```

What this equates to is find any documents that have `hello` in `tags`.  In would go a search where any of the items in the 'in' array match and `all` is where all items match - or in other words an exact match.

Comment: Yup.  I know I can do it like that.  But if I do it like this, then I have to iterate through all the search terms and make one query per search term.  This is not desirable. And also I am using django-tastypie-mongoengine.  I need to pass in a single queryset to it.  Unless I do something like this `Post.objects((Q(tags='hello') | Q(tags='world'))`.  But I am thinking if there is anything simplier.

Comment: Yea.  `in` looks good!  Just previously I got some other problems and I thought `in` doesn't work.